# Delay app start until RemoteConfig returns valus

Tags: firebase-remote-config

I have successfully implemented RemoteConfig in my application. Using the [fetchWithCompletionHandler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseremoteconfig/api/reference/Classes/FIRRemoteConfig#/c:objc(cs)FIRRemoteConfig(im)fetchWithCompletionHandler:): to retrieve the values from the Firebase server.

However, some of the RemoteConfig parameters are required for the app to startup and I cannot give them meaning-full default values (using [setDefaults](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseremoteconfig/api/reference/Classes/FIRRemoteConfig#/c:objc(cs)FIRRemoteConfig(im)setDefaults:)).

So my idea is to block the app startup until `fetchWithCompletion` handler has returned the values (I can do that asynchronously while presenting a nice spinner to the user).

However, I am wondering, will `fetchWithCompletion` return values immediately?
Or could it be that the user will have to wait a long time for the values to be loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not always return values immediately -- remember, you're making a network call to fetch those values from the server. Most of the time, this call is pretty fast, but depending on your user's network at the time, it could take a long time, and I believe the default timeout for this call is pretty long -- something like 30 seconds.

If you do want to block your app from running until this call is complete, I would recommend adding a loading screen (so your users know it's not frozen in case the call does take a few seconds), and implementing your own time-out that's a little shorter than the default.

Another option you might want to consider is the "Load up values for next time" approach, where you call `activateFetched` immediately (which will activate any values you might have downloaded in a previous session), then start a new fetch for values you can load the next time around. There's more info about it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TWJ_rR7K6g) if you're interested. This will mean your users' first session will have to be with default values, however, and it sounds like that might not be an option with your app.